# How to convert .arm certificate file to .pem format?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, convert

How to convert .arm certificate file to pem format?

I think .arm format ist used in IBM WebSphere, and I get certificates/public keys in these format. How can I convert there files to .pem or something?

Comment: What do the "arm" certs look like? Maybe they are already pem with a different extension.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, it is already pem-format. I just needed to rename them into .pem. Please write it as an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

.arm certs are the same thing as .pem certs, just rename it.